# pick up from his lap

Tags: word-choice

Does the expression **pick up something from some one's lap** sound natural to you? if not what would you suggest?
Context:

> She was supposed to be mollified now. In compliance, **she delivered a wide, reassuring smile and picked up the bag of hot dogs from Martin’s lap.**

Comment: Grammatically it's fine, but it leaves me wondering why on earth Martin is sitting there with a bag of hot dogs in his lap. That can't be sanitary.

Comment: @PhilSweet ... a little harsh...

Answer (score -1):

**gather up**  [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/gather) idiom

> 1. To collect or assemble certain things. A noun or pronoun can be used between "gather" and "up."

As in:

> ... and gathered up the bag of hot dogs from Martin’s lap.

Comment: But a bag (of anything) is a single object. And the question asks about picking up *something*, not several things. Is it possible to gather a single item?